# mongodb return number of matched expression

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have many document in collection I want to run a aggregation query. Let say sample doc are like as shown below

```
{"A":1,"B":2, "c":"x"}
{"A":3,"B":2, "c":"play"}
{"A":1,"B":2, "c":"test"}
```

to these doc I want to run a OR query and also I want to return number of or condition matched.
for example if query is

```
{"A":1, "A":3, "c":"test"}
```

it should return result like

```
[
    {"A":1,"B":2, "c":"x", "count":1}
    {"A":3,"B":2, "c":"play", "count", 1}
    {"A":1,"B":2, "c":"test", "count":2}
]
```

Comment: And what did you do so far?

Comment: I have a aggregation query using cond operator. but it is not returning the result

Comment: If you add your so far work, it should be good and shows people that you actually tried somethings before asking for help. check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384244/mongodb-multiple-aggregations-in-single-operation) and answer. you can use map-reduce probably

Comment: Did you try with the `$or` operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and evaluate your value based on specified conditions:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            count: {
                $add: [
                    { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$A", 1] }, 1, 0 ] },
                    { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$A", 3] }, 1, 0 ] },
                    { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$c", "test"] }, 1, 0 ] },
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "count": { $gt: 0 }
        }
    }
])
```